# edit the sound used in f curve

Tags: animation, modifiers, audio, fcurves, timeline

Hey is there a way to edit the sound that are baked to f curve. I have baked the sound av it works like I expect, but there are parts of the time line where I like the value to 0, but the sound is at a different value. I know I can sett the main lower, but that effects all the values. I need to set 4 or 5 part with 2 or 3 frames to 0 in the middle of baked sound.

Comment: Hi reinert welcome to Blender SE.  By 'value to 0', do you mean setting the volume of the sound, or the actual F-Curve-baked value to 0?

Comment: @MikeBelanger At some point, there isn't much of a difference. That being said, I think he means the latter, due to "I know I can sett the main lower."

Answer (score 2):

Despite the name, f-curves can contain either curve data or sampled data. The sampled data that is used when you bake a sound to an fcurve is not editable.

There are [methods available](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.FCurve.html#bpy.types.FCurve.convert_to_samples) in python to convert between curves and sampled data but blender does not provide a way to do this through the user interface. There is an addon that adds this to the [graph editor here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/qwenger/BAddons/master/GraphEditor_ConvertFCurves/graph_editor_convert_fcurves.py).

After installing and enabling the addon you can convert the baked sound to curves which you can then edit as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, that's a good question...

Good answer to it, though!

### Solution

From your question, I assume that you have already *Bake Sound to F-Curves*-ed and know how to do that. If you don't, comment, let me know, and I will add steps on how to do it.

You can set the value to 0 at any frame or length of frames with an *F-Curve modifier* (similar to the concept of an *Object modifier* found in the *Properties panel*). With the sound F-Curve selected, key <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> and click on *Envelope*.

*Add F-Curve Modifier menu:*

[image]

Key <kbd>N</kbd> to toggle open/close the *Graph Editor Property panel*. Scroll down to the *Modifiers* dropdown. Make the panel bigger. You should see options like the following.

*This modifier setup will set the F-Curve value to 0 between frames 100 and 105, inclusive:*

[image]

The top three values are default. The next three, I got by clicking the *Add Point* button. The *Frame:* value should somewhere between the *Start:* and *End:* values in the *Restrict Frame Range* dropdown, although it doesn't really matter. As long as the *Min:* and *Max: Control Point* values are equal, that is the value that the F-Curve will be set to between the *Start:* and *End:* values.

*Curve. Note the 0 value from frame 100-105:*

[image]